# Is there the exclusive list of Pythagorean triples? If there is, what is the general pattern for it?

Tags: number-theory

Is there the exclusive list of Pythagorean triples? If there is, what is the general pattern for it?

What about [Euclid's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple)? Does it generate all the Pythagorean triples?

More explicitly, if $a,b,c$ is a Pythagorean triple, then does it satisfy 
$$
a = m^2+n^2, b=2mn, c= m^2 + n^2
$$
for some numbers $m,n$?

If you don't mind, could you give me a full rigorous statement of what I tried to describe right above (that is, the necessary condition of Pythagorean triples)?

Comment: A Pythagorean triple never satisfies the conditions you list, because you have a typo that accidentally equated two of the sides, implying that $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A direct quote from the Wikipedia article you linked to:

> Despite generating all primitive triples, Euclid's formula does not produce all triples. This can be remedied by inserting an additional parameter $k$ to the formula. The following will generate all Pythagorean triples uniquely:
>
> $$a = k\cdot(m^2 - n^2) ,\ \, b = k\cdot(2mn) ,\ \, c = k\cdot(m^2 + n^2)$$
>
> where $m, n,$ and $k$ are positive integers with $m > n$, $m − n$ odd, and with $m$ and $n$ coprime.

Comment: Oh my bad. But THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 1):

From [Tree of primitive Pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_Pythagorean_triples)

> F. J. M. Barning[$^{[2]}$](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/7151/7151A.pdf) showed that when any of the three matrices
>   $$    \begin{array}{lcr} A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 2 \\ 2 & -1 & 2 \\ 2 & -2 & 3 \end{bmatrix} & B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix} & C = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & 2 \\ -2 & 1 & 2 \\ -2 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \end{array} $$
>   is multiplied on the right by a column vector whose components form a Pythagorean triple, then the result is another column vector whose components are a different Pythagorean triple

Answer (score 1):

$$x=a+\sqrt{2 a b},\quad y=b+\sqrt{2 a b},\quad z=a+b+\sqrt{2 a b}$$

generates all pythagerean triplets

$$x^2+y^2=z^2$$